# Force the browser to send http request for an image

Tags: javascript, image, http-headers, browser-cache

I have an app that loads images dynamically with JavaScript and draws them to a canvas. The images can change, but I also want to leverage caching, so I am using the last modified http header and sending 304 response when the image is not modified. That is all fine and well and seems to be working...

But there's a strange thing that is happening (so far only tested in Chrome and Safari on OSX) where occasionally the browser just neglects to send a request for an image! In the script, I make a `new Image()`, and the `onload` function fires, but when I use the network inspector, the request is never made. I also can confirm on the server side that a request was not received.

The original request with an empty cache response has these headers:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:25937
Content-Type:image/png
ETag:Thu, 10 May 2012 20:48:13 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 10 May 2012 20:48:13 GMT
```

Shouldn't the browser make a new request every time for this image, since it has the last-modified header? When I run a test, the browser seems to make only one new request every minute or so (regardless how many copies of the same image I try to load)... Is this the expected behavior? Is there some header combination that will force the browser to check every time if an image is modified? Or perhaps some JavaScript magic that will do the trick?

Comment: What are you using to make your request? This could be something specific to the method or library you're using to make the request if it sees a request for an identical URI within a certain timeout period.

Comment: @ZachB I am not using any library. I am doing plain JS, i.e. `var img = new Image(); img.onload = function () { /* ... */ }; img.src = "someimage.png";`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found a solution to your problem or not but I had been struggling with exactly the same issue and I think I have a solution now. What I did was use an ajax call to make the request and instead of returning the image as a file of type image/jpeg, I returned the data as base64_encoded data and on the client side I render the img by setting the src to a data uri. Using jQuery, it sort of looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: imageURL,
    headers: {'Max-Age':0},
    success: function(d){
                jQuery(imgElement).attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,'+d);
             },
    error: function(){/*handle error*/},
    complete: function(){/* handle complete*/}
 });
```

This works for me. I hope that helps you.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work for me. What headers are you sending on the server side?